# How do I filter jquery datatables in initialization

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I would like to ask if there is a way to filter datatable server-side in initilization?

I've tried a code that goes something like this:

```
function listTable(arg1, param2, value3) {
var searchTbl = $("#tblsearch").dataTable({
                    "bRetrieve": true,
                    "bProcessing": true,
                    "bServerSide": true,                   
                    "sAjaxSource": "server-side.php",
                    "bPaginate": false,
                    "bLengthChange": false,
                    "bFilter": false,
                    "bSort": true,
                    "bInfo": false,
                    "bAutoWidth": false
                });

searchTbl.filter(arg1, param2, value3);
searchTbl.fnDraw();
}
```

but it did not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Salute brod,

As what I've understand. You are trying to filter your records to display on jquery dataTables from your server-side ***`server-side.php`*** script.

It will only work if you may provide a sample of your ***`server-side.php`*** script.

However to provide you with better understanding and input, your desired filter will all depend on the database query are executing on the server-side script. For example:

> "SELECT `column_1`, `column_2`, `column_3` WHERE `column_1` = 'some
>   value' AND `column_2` LIKE '%another value%' GROUP BY `column_3`"

A very good example is in this link: [DataTables server-side processing example](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/data_sources/server_side.html)

Where you may modify this part:

```
/* Individual column filtering */
    for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ )
    {
        if ( isset($_GET['bSearchable_'.$i]) && $_GET['bSearchable_'.$i] == "true" && $_GET['sSearch_'.$i] != '' )
        {
            if ( $sWhere == "" )
            {
                $sWhere = "WHERE ";
            }
            else
            {
                $sWhere .= " AND ";
            }
            $sWhere .= "`".$aColumns[$i]."` LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['sSearch_'.$i])."%' ";
        }
    }
```

And in this way the data that will compose your json output to be passed to and parsed by jquery dataTable will be filtered desirably.

Answer (score 1):

whether you are trying to search data in the table ? If so below is the part

```
function doSearch() {
        var searchText = document.getElementById('searchTerm').value;
        var targetTable = document.getElementById('mytable');
        var targetTableColCount;

        //Loop through table rows
        for (var rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < targetTable.rows.length; rowIndex++) {
            var rowData = '';

            //Get column count from header row
            if (rowIndex == 0) {
                targetTableColCount = targetTable.rows.item(rowIndex).cells.length;
                continue; //do not execute further code for header row.
            }

            //Process data rows. (rowIndex >= 1)
            for (var colIndex = 0; colIndex < targetTableColCount; colIndex++) {
                var cellText = '';

                if (navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer')
                    cellText = targetTable.rows.item(rowIndex).cells.item(colIndex).innerText;
                else
                    cellText = targetTable.rows.item(rowIndex).cells.item(colIndex).textContent;

                rowData += cellText;

            }

            //If search term is not found in row data
            //then hide the row, else show
            if (rowData.indexOf(searchText) == -1)
                targetTable.rows.item(rowIndex).style.display = 'none';
            else
                targetTable.rows.item(rowIndex).style.display = 'table-row';
        }
    }
```